# as I can move my size dialog box by dragging a button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialog, touch-event

dragging the button in the dialog, I need to change the dimensions of my dialog, depending on where you drag the button.

```
        final Dialog hojaDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.NewDialog);
        hojaDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hoja);
        final Window window = hojaDialog.getWindow();
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
        wlp.width=400;
        wlp.height=800;
        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);
        final Button btn = (Button)hojaDialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    float oldXvalue = me.getX();
                    float oldYvalue = me.getY();

                }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE  ){
                    int oldXvalue = (int)me.getX();
                    int oldYvalue = (int)me.getY();


                    hojaDialog.getWindow().setLayout(oldXvalue, oldYvalue);

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```